# Integration of CPP with Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c

I want to call a CPP function from Objective C. I have written the function in CPP. I have tried to call the CPP function from test.mm file, but I am getting following error message.

error: 'functionName' was not declared in this scope

I have written the function 'functionName' in testCPP.cpp & testCPP.h

Please help me to resolve it.

```
//Objective-C (.mm)
#import "MergeAudios.h"
#import "MergeAudioFiles.h" // cpp header file

@implementation MergeAudios

-(void)mergeAudioFile1:(CFURLRef)path1 file2:(CFURLRef)path2 withFile:(CFURLRef)path3{
    CombineAudioFiles(path1, path2, path3);
}

@end
// CPP (.cpp)

void CombineAudioFiles(CFURLRef sourceURL1, CFURLRef sourceURL2, CFURLRef destinationURL) 
{
......
......
}
```

Comment: What's in `MergeAudioFiles.h`?

Comment: MergeAudioFiles.h is like testCPP.h

Comment: Yes, but is there a declaration for `CombineAudioFiles` in `MergeAudioFiles.h`? If we can't see the code, we can't help.

Comment: Sorry, In my .cpp file, having 3 methods. I did not declare 'CombineAudioFiles' in .h file. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Did you `#include "testCPP.h"`?</strike>

The functions need to be declared in `MergeAudioFiles.h`, just like in normal C++.